# Elegant regex using pandas - extract dose info

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a data frame like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text_1':['WHITE SOFT PARAFFIN 100G', 'VITAMIN B12 1MG/ML INJ 10ML','vitamin B1 100mg, B6 200mg, B12 200mcg tab','UREA CREAM 10% BP 100G', 'TOBRAMYCIN 0.3%/DEXA 1% EYE DROP 5ML','TERAzosin 5MG TAB (HYTRIN)','SODIUM CHLORIDE 0.9% EYE DROP 5ML/10ML']})
```

I would like to extract the dose information from the list of drugs shown in sample dataframe.

While, I am able to achieve 90% accuracy, I would like to check with you on how can I do it in the foolproof way or a robust way to minimize capturing unwanted info

For example, I tried the below and it produced an incorrect output

```
df['text_1'].str.findall('[0-9]+\s*[mgMG/lLcC]+')
```

[image]

The last row should have been `5ML/10ML` but it is split into two (which is incorrect)

Another hint is I know that all my dose values will start with `number optionally followed by a space and unit like` MG`, MCG`, `ML`,`G`, `g`, `mg`, `mcg` or `ml` etc.

For ex: `WHITE SOFT PARAFFIN 100G`, I would like to extract `100G`. Similarly, for `VITAMIN B12 1MG/ML INJ 10ML`, I would like to extract `1MG/ML and 10ML`. We extract both `1MG/ML` and `10ML` because it satisfies my hint

So, I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```py
df.text_1.str.findall(r"\d+\s*[mc]*[lg]+/*(?:\d*\s*[mc]*[lg]+)?", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

output:

```
0                    [100G]
1            [1MG/ML, 10ML]
2    [100mg, 200mg, 200mcg]
3                    [100G]
4                     [5ML]
5                     [5MG]
6                [5ML/10ML]
Name: text_1, dtype: object
```

on regex:

- we need at least some numerics: `\d+`
- space is optional `\s*`
- a prefix like `m` or `c` may be there `[mc]*`
- the real unit is expected to be there `[lg]+`
- a slash is optional at the end of these `/*`

the second part is slightly modified part of this, specifically

- a number may or may not be there after slash i.e. `\d*`
- this whole part is optional `?`
- and not to be captured `?:`

and we use case-insensitivity to save some space from `M` etc.